# Creating Custom Text Representation In CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to represent a text like below image, how can i do this using CSS and HTML?
 [Custom Text Representation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pClrC.png)

Note: This is not text input field. I just want to display the text.

Comment: That's literally a Fieldset with a Legend tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp

Comment: Im not taking any input from the user here, I want to display the text which are alread stored in data base, e.g ANDRIOD TV ROOM 1 is not user input.

Comment: @PavanShetty there is no need to add inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try the below code.

```
<style>
.text-content{
position: relative;
border: 5px solid;
border-radius: 20px;
padding: 20px 0;
}
.text-content span{
position: absolute;
background: #fff;
left: 25px;
top: -18px;
padding: 0 10px;
font-size: 22px;
}
</style>

<h1 class="text-content">
  <span>TV NAME</span>
   ANDRIOD TV ROOM 1
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use The HTML fieldset element:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>TV NAME</legend>
  ANDRIOD TV ROOM 1
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: hey, he do not want get that through fieldset

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also. I think it's perfect for you.

```css
fieldset {
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
}
legend {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>TV NAME</legend>
  <span>ANDRIOD TV ROOM 1</span>
 </fieldset>
```